# Why does RM not autocomplete in a file that runs OK?

Tags: rubymine

Here's a line from a file that runs perfectly:

```
@browser.link(:id, "lnkTransactions").click
```

"link" is in Watir::Container

"click" is in Watir::Element

In my gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'watir'
gem 'watir-webdriver'
```

I use:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'
```

So what do I need to to in order to show "link" and "click" in the autocomplete dropdown list?